# Ruby: Unique Instance Variables

Tags: ruby, variables

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :name_balance
  def initialize(name, name_balance=0)
    @name = name
    @name_balance = name_balance
    puts "Hi, #{name}. You have $#{name_balance}!"
  end
end

class Bank 
  attr_accessor :bank_name, :bank_balance
  def initialize(bank_name)
    @bank_name = bank_name
    puts "#{bank_name} bank was just created."
  end

  def open_account(person, bank_balance=0)
    @bank_balance = bank_balance
    puts "#{person.name}, thanks for opening an account at #{bank_name}!"
  end

  def deposit(person, amount)
    @amount = amount
    @bank_balance += amount
    person.name_balance -= amount
    puts "#{person.name} deposited $#{amount} to #{bank_name}. #{person.name} has $#  {person.name_balance}. #{person.name}'s account has $#{bank_balance}."
  end   
end
```

```
chase = Bank.new("JP Morgan Chase")
wells_fargo = Bank.new("Wells Fargo")

me = Person.new("Shehzan", 500)
friend1 = Person.new("John", 1000)

chase.open_account(me)
chase.open_account(friend1)

wells_fargo.open_account(me)
wells_fargo.open_account(friend1)

chase.deposit(me, 200)
chase.deposit(friend1, 300)
```

I'm having issues making `@bank_balance` unique to the Person (Shehzan, John). When I call `chase.deposit(me, 200)` I get

> Shehzan deposited $200 to JP Morgan Chase. Shehzan has $300. Shehzan's account has $200.

which is correct. But when I call `chase.deposit(friend1, 300)` after calling `chase.deposit(me, 200)` I get

> John deposited $300 to JP Morgan Chase. John has $700. John's account has $500.

which is incorrect.

John's account should only have $300, not $500. I believe whats happening is I'm storing the $200 from Shehzan's account in `@bank_balance`, then adding $300 to `@bank_balance` when I execute `chase.deposit(friend1, 300)`.

I think I need to add something to the `open_account` method to make `@bank_balance` unique to `@name`. I'm just not sure what...

Answer (score 1):

I would say that your problem is in the way you've modeled your situation, not in the way that Ruby's instance variables work.

In particular, it feels like you're missing an `Account` model: A `Bank` maintains a list of `Accounts`, each `Account` is owned by a `Person` and each `Person` maintains a list of their `Accounts` at various `Banks`.

I assume this is a learning exercise (i.e., you're not actually setting up a bank), so I'll suggest you consider the above and try again instead of writing it for you myself.